# Is the derivative of a simple closed curve $\alpha$ with certain properties injective?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

Let $\alpha : I \to \mathbb R^2$, where $ I \subset \mathbb R$, be a simple closed curve with positive speed and curvature, does it follow that $\alpha’$ is also injective, as a vector field on $\alpha$, as well, except at the end points?

This came out while I was trying to prove that $\int_{a}^{b} \kappa(t) dt = 2\pi$, where $\alpha$ is such a curve with unit speed, $\kappa$ is the curvature of $\alpha$ and $I = [a,b]$. I was trying to prove that the derivative map $\alpha$ is injective to show that the integral cannot be greater than $2\pi$.

Intuitively, this should be obvious but I couldn’t find a way to show it, thank you.

Comment: What does "positive speed" mean?

Comment: @MoisheKohan It means that it is not $0$ anywhere.

Comment: That the curve parameterization has unit speed means that $|\alpha'(t)| = 1$, so $\alpha'(t)$ is always on the unit circle. Assuming $\alpha'$ is differentiable, there's a differentiable function $\theta(t)$ where $\alpha'(t) = (\cos \theta(t), \sin \theta(t))$. I think $\theta'$ should always have the same sign as $\kappa$...

Comment: @aschepler Indeed, $\kappa = \theta'$.